# Building ML to finding the closest matching image based on users drawing

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to build a ML Agent to find the closest matching image from a given set. The user will draw something and the agent should list the closest matching images.

Very similar to these examples

1. https://sketchx.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/
2. Emoji search in Android keyboard

One unique problem I've is, each image will represent a category. Imagine we have product images and user will draw something and we have to find the products close to the drawing. So category in my case will be product Id.

[image]

I would like to evaluate the approach before trying out.

There are lot of examples to classify images, however if I use the item identifier instead of category it should work. But am trying to find the best approach for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good project you can research to find information on this specific task, it is Google [quickdraw](https://quickdraw.withgoogle.com/data). It has 50 million drawings across 345 categories and it was used in Google autoDraw. AutoDraw guesses what you’re trying to draw.

You can use quickdraw dataset to train a neural network (Sequence-to-Sequence Variational Autoencoder) in order to get draws from your Sketches. for more info on this read [this papper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.03477.pdf)

Classified Sketches into categories is a difficult task because Sketches are a high-level representation that does not always convey enough information to distinguish between different categories.

The the best approach will depend on your specific needs

Comment: Hi Jony, Thanks for your response. I've a unique problem in image classification. I've updated my question with more information. In my case, I am trying to identify the product based on the user's hand art. So there is only one image for a product from which the ML agent can learn

Comment: in that case, you are not going to get a good performance with natural photos classification algorithm, take a look at Sketch-a-Net [arXiv:1501.07873v3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.07873v3)  This architecture Beats Humans and can help with your problem.